# Чи коректно називати прийменники та інші службові частини мови "словами"?

Tags: прийменники

У деяких джерелах вживається фраза `службові слова` або `службова частина мови` по відношенню до прийменників. У першому випадку уточнюють, що службові слова не є повнозначними словами.

Згідно [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA), прийменники не мають самостійного лексичного значення, тому членами речення не виступають.

Основні [підходи](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96) до статусу визначення прийменника в українському мовознавстві:

- прийменник як службове слово з послабленим лексичним значенням (найпоширеніша версія);
- прийменник є морфемлю;
- прийменник не є ні словом, ні морфемою. Структурно він набуває ознак слова, функціонально — ознак морфеми.

Український правопис теж [вживає](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf) словосполучення `службові слова`.

Я, своєю чергою, пам'ятаю зі школи, що прийменники не є словами.

А, отже, коректно говорити, що у фразі `вершник на коні` **два слова** або **фраза складається з трьох частин мови** або **фраза складається з трьох частин речення**.

Як правильно?

Comment: «Я, своєю чергою, пам'ятаю зі школи, що прийменники не є словами» — нам у школі казали навпаки :).

Answer (score 1):

**Службові слова**, неповнозначні (систематичні) слова — вільні морфеми, що інтонаційно об'єднуються зі словом, словосполученням чи реченням і виражають, подібно до словотвірних і словозмінних (флексійних)) зв'язаних морфем, різні стосунки між повнозначними словами й реченнями, об'єднуючи їх або надаючи їм різних значеннєвих відтінків. До [**С. с.**](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) в українській мові належать прийменники, сполучники й частки.

**Службові слова** - це такі частини мови, що не виступають членами речення.

Отже `вершник на коні` - це фраза, яка складається з трьох слів.